# MAMP server starts but website won't load

Tags: localhost, server, mamp

Today I started my MAMP local server and my Wordpress installation would not load. It will attempt to load for 15-20 seconds and then give me an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. Yesterday everything worked fine, and I made absolutely no changes to MAMP or my website's files to cause this issue, so this issue is really frustrating and mysterious to me.

I don't think that the actual MAMP server is an issue because when I start up the server I can click 'Open WebStart page' and it will load fine, it is only my website itself that won't load.

I also tried to change the ports from the default 8888 & 8889 to 80 & 3306 as was suggested by someone in a forum but that made no difference either.

Like I said, I am using the same ports as yesterday and the same IP that I was using to connect to my localhost, but today for some reason it won't load. Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem which involved a corrupt Wordpress database. The problem ended up having nothing to do with MAMP. I ended up fixing the issue by restoring my Wordpress installation from a backup which I luckily had thanks to [Updraft Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/). If anybody else is having this problem consider the possibility that your database may be corrupt.